# Finding n and c in single sampling plan

Tags: sampling, binomial-distribution, discrete-data, quality-control

I am learning a quality control course and in Single sampling scheme for attribute type inspection  I don't understand the method used for calculating the values of $n$ and $c$.
The method is as follows.

Specify two levels of quality $p_0$ with probability of acceptance $1-\alpha$ and $p_1$ with probability of acceptance $\beta$.
Using binomial distribution $\sum_{x=0}^{c}{n\choose x}p_{0}^x(1-p_0)^{n-x}>=1-\alpha$

$\sum_{x=0}^{c}{n\choose x}p_{1}^x(1-p_1)^{n-x}<=\beta$

As this is difficult to solve chi squared approximation is used.
$\sum_{x=0}^{c}{n\choose x}p_{0}^x(1-p_0)^{n-x}=\int_{2np_0}^\infty\chi^2_{2c+2}dx$
If the two points corresponding to $1-\alpha$ and $\beta $ are respectively $\chi^2_{(1)}$ and $\chi^2_{(2)}$ then it says to find from the table point where $\frac{\chi^2_{(1)}}{\chi^2_{(2)}}=$$\frac{2np_0}{2np_1}$.

Is this done by going through all the table values for different degrees of freedom of chi squared and finding two values for $\chi^2_{(1)}$ and $\chi^2_{(2)}$ such that their ratio =$p_0/p_1$

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @whuber I don't understand how $\chi^2_{(1)}$ and $\chi^2_{(2)}$ are found through table values

Comment: OK.  Please tell us what information you have and do not have.  I presume you have specified (at a minimum) $\alpha, \beta, p_0$, and $p_1$, but I do not see any clear connection between "$\chi^2_{(1)}$" and "$c$", for instance: the presence of the "$1$" in the subscript tells me that $2c+2=1$, whence $c=-1/2$, but that is not a meaningful value for $c$, so you must be mistaken somewhere in your notation.

Comment: @whuber 1 and 2 in chi squared are used only for notation to say that they are two chi square values.These two chi square values can have any degree of freedom such that the ratio of these two chi squared values=$p_0/p_1$.But wouldn't it be difficult to go through the entire table looking at all degrees of freedoms and finding two chi squared values s.t their ratio=$p_0/p_1$.

Comment: Sure--that's why we use programmable computers. They can do that work almost instantly.  It's still not clear what you are asking, due to your inconsistent notation, and it's a little hard to reverse-engineer the theory you're using, due to the use of approximations (which seem unnecessary, given that computers easily compute cumulative binomial distribution values).

Comment: Can you point to a reference?